# PostgreSQL Connection String with ODBC driver in C#, Keyword not supported: driver

Tags: c#, postgresql, odbc, connection-string

Lately I've been trying to connect a PostgreSQL 9.6 database on my C# project but I've been struggling setting up the connection string correctly due to "Keyword not supported:driver".

After having read tons of information, I downloaded the ODBC.NET, I registered PostgreSQL in ODBC Data Sources (32x), referenced the Microsoft.Data.Odbc.dll in my project's directory and managed to have a successful connection with my database in the Visual Studio's Ultimate 2013, but when it came to accessing the data something went wrong.

This is my connection string and a glimpse of my project:

[image]

Furthermore this is my data source information:

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use Npgsql?

Comment: @Hambone At last switched everything to SqlServer and solved all my problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use ODBC to connect to PostgreSQL database use [OdbcConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.aspx)

You can then instantiate a connection using DSN as ODBC data source identifier.

```
OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=PostgreSQL30");
```

as specified [here](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/csharp/ado-net-odbc.html)

There are also other ways to connect to PostreSQL without using ODBC driver. You might want to look at [Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/) .net library or EntityFramework with Npgsql library. More info about usage can be found [here](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html)